# Angular: Trying to turn my function into rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a function that is implemented and works properly
I want to make it rxjs with filter in rxjs directory use both pipe and includes

And update with subscribe

```
  posts: Post[] = [];
   validPosts: Post[] = [];
   authorName: string = "";
```

this is my function:

```
SearchPostsByName($event: Event) {
    const searchKey = ($event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;

    if (searchKey === '') {
      this.validPosts = this.posts;
      return;
    }
    
    this.validPosts = this.posts.filter(
      value => value.authorName.includes(this.searchName)
    );
  }
```

Comment: You're looking for `PipeTransform`, I guess? https://angular.io/api/core/PipeTransform

Comment: @W.S. No, I want to implement a function within a service when I use rxjs and call it in components
And update with subscribe

Comment: Ok, and what do you've so far? You've an input field, which would serve as your search filter? You're listening to keypress event, and based upon the state changes you want to filter the posts. Are you able to share a simple setup of your environment within StackBlitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a search using an input field, you bind the input element to a `@ViewChild`.

```html
<label>Search Posts </label>
<div>
  <input #search type="text" [value]="filterInput" />
</div>
```

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild('search', { static: true }) search: ElementRef;

  private subscription: Subscription;

  public posts$: Observable<Post[]>;
  public filterInput: string = '';
  public errorMessage: string = '';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private appService: AppService
  ) {}

  ...

}
```

In the `AfterViewInit`, you add an observable to the `keyup` event of the element. Through a `pipe`, you `map` the event to its value. You add a `debounceTime` so the observable doesn't emit too often, and you only listen to changes trough `distinctUntilChanged`.

Within the subscription itself, you check the input value and change the url `queryParams` based upon the input.

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.subscription = fromEvent(this.search.nativeElement, 'keyup')
    .pipe(
      map((event: KeyboardEvent) => (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value),
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    )
    .subscribe((filter) => {
      const queryParams = filter ? { queryParams: { filter } } : undefined;
      this.router.navigate(['.'], {
        relativeTo: this.route,
        ...queryParams,
      });
    });
}
```

During `OnInit`, you `switchMap` the observable of the route's `queryParams` to a new observable which will fetch the filtered posts from your database through the service. Upon a window refresh the filter query from the url will also be set as the input value.

```js
private fetchPosts() {
  this.posts$ = this.route.queryParams
    .pipe(
      switchMap((params) => {
        if (params.filter) this.filterInput = params.filter;
        return this.appService.fetchPosts(params.filter);
      })
    )
    .pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        this.errorMessage = err;
        return EMPTY;
      })
    );
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.fetchPosts();
}
```

In order to show the content, you subscribe to the observable through an `async` pipe within the html.

```html
<div *ngIf="posts$ | async as posts; else loadingOrError">
  <div *ngIf="!posts.length">
    <h3>No posts found</h3>
  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <b>{{ post?.content }}</b>
    <br/>
    <i>
      by <b>{{ post?.authorName }}</b> at
      <b>{{ post?.date | date: 'dd MMMM YYYY' }}</b>
    </i>
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #loadingOrError>
  <span *ngIf="errorMessage; else loading">
    An error occured while loading the posts: {{ errorMessage }}
  </span>
  <ng-template #loading> ...loading... </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

[State management, using RxJS | URL vs local client state](https://pieter-hogent.github.io/web4/9_state.html#/urlvslocalclient)

[StackBlitz | Filter through RxJS](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mrdpgx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)